# Execute command on docker container from remote machine

Tags: python, bash, docker, fabric

I have docker running on Host. There are two docker containers on this host i.e container_1 and container_2. Now I want to execute some commands on container_1 from my remote dev machine.

pipe separated commands i.e,

```
sudo docker exec -it  container_1 sudo find <dir> - type f -iname *_abc_* -print0 | du --files0-from - -b | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$1} END{print sum}'
```

Form above command only first command till first pipe execute on docker container and next set of command execute on host.

I am using python fabric api to execute this from remote machine.

Is there any way to execute this full command on container from remote machine ?

Comment: that's because pipe command actually gets executed on your host, try this, it may work for you: `sudo docker exec -it container_1 bash -c "sudo find - type f -iname _abc_ -print0 | du --files0-from - -b | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$1} END{print sum}'"`

Comment: @Boynux, it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'll create an Answer for that, it'd be great if you mark it a correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because pipe command actually gets executed on your host, try this, it may work for you:

```
sudo docker exec -it container_1 bash -c "sudo find - type f -iname_abc_ -print0 | du --files0-from - -b | awk 'BEGIN{sum=0} {sum+=$1} END{print sum}'"
```